# About Optic Fiber Connection

Tags: fiber, sfp

I have a practical doubt. Can someone explain to me if i can connect 2 networks equipments using XFP and SFP+, MM the two, accross a SM fiber, ´cause i recently made the escenario and did not work.

The 2 connectors, XFP and SFP+ work on 850 nm, on a distance of 300m, every of that a just checked.

The link never came up, but the same link where connected to other slot using 1Gb SFP and instantly came UP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multimode SFPs (MM) are incompatible with singlemode (SM) fiber.

Comment: Oh thanks, i see. I was wrong then, ...another question about that, If SFPs MM are incompatible with SM fiber, by some reason, the contrary, SFP SM can work with MM fiber??

Comment: Generally no, although occasionally it will work.  But I would never depend on it.

Comment: @Ron answer is correct in theory. The truth is that sometimes it works. You have here a Cisco case described where you can user MTP to adapt it http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/product_bulletin_c25-530836.html

Comment: Yes, some transceivers that are typically designed for SM can work on MM. However often they will require the use of "mode conditioning" patch cords on each side, and these cables can be more expensive (because they are a require specialized manufacturing and are a low volume seller) than buying the correct optics. See [this Cisco document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/product_bulletin_c25-530836.html) for details.